# SQL query with complex case-when statement

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I have a table with the following schema

```
id  data  rank  usage
 1  hi     19    H
 2  he     14    M
 3  me      9    L
 4  ke     23    H
 5  jo     11    M
 6  km      2    L
 7  lo      4    L
 8  no     12    M
 9  my     20    H
```

I want to do something like

`If max(rank) where usage='L'>=25 Then Select all records where usage='H'
Else If max(rank) where usage='M'>=25 Select all records where usage='L' and records where usage='M'
ELSE Select all records`

SQL does not support statements like:

`SELECT CASE WHEN (select max(rank) from my_table where usage='L') >= 100`

So, how should I write this query?

Comment: You can try storing the max rank in a variable then use that variable to perform an IF ELSE sql statement.

Comment: `SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT *,
               CASE WHEN usage = 'L' AND Max([rank]) OVER() >= 25 THEN 'H'
                 WHEN usage = 'M' AND Max([rank]) OVER() >= 25 THEN 'L'
                 ELSE NULL
               END AS intr
        FROM   Yourtable) a
WHERE  usage = intr
        OR intr IS NULL 
`

Comment: Add the requested results to your post

Answer (score 0):

```
select  id,data,rank,usage

from   (select  *
               ,max(case usage when 'L' then rank end) over () max_rank_L   
               ,max(case usage when 'M' then rank end) over () max_rank_M

        from    mytable 
        ) t

where   usage rlike case
                        when max_rank_L >= 25 then '^(H)$'
                        when max_rank_M >= 25 then '^(L|M)$'
                        else                       '()'
                    end
```

Answer (score -1):

You can apply the logic in the filter. This query should provide you what you need:

```
select *
  from table1
 where 
       ((select max(rank) from table1 where usage = 'L') >= 25 and usage = 'H')
       or ((select max(rank) from table1 where usage = 'L') < 25 
            and (select max(rank) from table1 where usage = 'M') >= 25 
            and usage = 'L')
       or ((select max(rank) from table1 where usage = 'L') < 25
           and (select max(rank) from table1 where usage = 'M') < 25)
```